# What fraction of digital health care data is openly accessible?

Tags: medical

(1) says that:

> In 2012, the worldwide
>   amount of digital health care data was estimated to be around
>   500 petabytes, expected to reach 25,000 petabytes in 2020, of
>   which approximately 80% is unstructured.

What fraction of it is openly accessible?

---

(1) Van Poucke S, Thomeer M, Heath J, Vukicevic M
Are Randomized Controlled Trials the (G)old Standard? From Clinical Intelligence to Prescriptive Analytics
J Med Internet Res 2016;18(7):e185
URL: http://www.jmir.org/2016/7/e185
DOI: 10.2196/jmir.5549
PMID: 27383622